# How do we know if people are from google, ask, or another big company?

Tags: discussion

I just saw [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/31076/6901), which says that it was written by someone from ask.com. I also recall reading answers by people from google, seomoz, etc. Is there any way that we can verify to make sure that they are for real, and not just someone saying they are part of a company that they aren't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The veracity of a user's claimed association should be apparent in his or her answers and the manner in which he or she behaves.

If a user appears to be claiming association to the detriment of the company or organization he or she claims to be affiliated with, please flag for moderator follow-up - we can't prevent people from trying such antics, but it should be fairly easy to shut down imposters.